# Unable to create temp file for insert values in hive

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have installed hive 1.2 in a Linux server and started metastore successfully when I am inserting data in a table I am getting below error.Please suggest some solution.

```
/oradata_iscsi/hive/bin>hive
ls: cannot access /oradata_iscsi/spark/lib/spark-assembly-*.jar: No such file or directory

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/oradata_iscsi/hive/lib/hive-common-1.2.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
hive> Insert into test values(1);
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10293]: Unable to create temp file for insert values File /tmp/hive/ora12c/6a9e3ee7-620f-476c-939c-64a49c6a0a7e/_tmp_space.db/Values__Tmp__Table__1/data_file could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 1 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1559)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3245)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:663)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:482)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:975)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2040)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2036)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1692)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2034)
```